# Como fazer cálculo de juros e desconto em uma linha?

Tags: java

No meu botão eu declarei assim:

```
numero_de_parcelas = Integer.parseInt(txtNumeroParcelas.getText());
juros = Float.parseFloat(txtJuros.getText());
desconto = Float.parseFloat(txtDesconto.getText());
valor_da_venda = Float.parseFloat(txtValorVenda.getText());
valor_da_parcela = valor_da_venda / numero_de_parcelas;
```

Porém quando vou mostrar o total na tabela com os juros e descontos não funciona meu cálculo:

```
Mparcela.setPreco_parcelas((valor_da_parcela+(valor_da_parcela*
    (juros/100)))-(valor_da_parcela-((valor_da_parcela*(desconto/100)))));
          mp.setPreco_total(Float.parseFloat(txtTotal.getText()));
```

Só funciona o juros sozinho quando eu deixo assim:

```
Mparcela.setPreco_parcelas(valor_da_parcela+(valor_da_parcela*(juros/100)));
mp.setPreco_total(Float.parseFloat(txtTotal.getText()));
```

Mas o desconto eu não sei como fazer...

Alguem sabe?

Comment: Textbox? Nunca vi isso em Java. No seria jtextfield?

Comment: isso! me desculple...

Comment: Assim:  mp.setPreco_parcelas((valor_da_parcela+(valor_da_parcela*(juros/100)))-(valor_da_parcela+((valor_da_parcela*(desconto/100)))));não moço, agora ele me trouxe um numero negativo

Comment: `(valor_da_parcela+(valor_da_parcela*juros/100))-(valor_da_parcela*desconto/100)`, confirme no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/4blTRo)